# Typescript strict mode filter Observable

Tags: typescript

Created an Angular11 project with `strict` set to `true` in `CompilerOptions` as I thought it's a good idea to detect potential errors at compile time.

Then try to follow the Angular official website tutorial which doesn't turn on `strict` mode.
In the example, it uses `Observable` when a service returns some hard-coded mock data. Now this doesn't compile due to `hero` potentially is `undefined`. And the compiler complains that `type Hero | undefined cannot be assigned to type Hero`. Note that `HEROES` is hard-coded mock data but in production it's retrieved from a database. Turning off `strict` mode gets rid of the complier errors but what if I want to turn on `strict` mode and the data is not mocked. How to deal this?

```
getHero(id:number): Observable<Hero> {
    return of(HEROES.find((hero => hero.id === id)));
  }
```

Comment: It happens because `HEROES.find` returns `Hero | undefined` value. So you must either change the return type correspondingly or somehow guarantee that you always return the `Hero` typed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for result where the var `hero` is a valid `Hero`:

```
getHero(id:number): Observable<Hero> {
    return of(HEROES.find((hero => hero && hero.id === id)));
}
```

Comment: It's not `hero` argument that is a problem.